# Eclipse RCP: bundle activation upon resource request

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, osgi-bundle, lazy-initialization

> The Eclipse-LazyStart header is used to specify if a bundle should be started before the first class **or resource** is accessed from that bundle

Taken from the official Eclipse [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fbundle_manifest.html).
It can be inferred from this sentence that if one specifies `Eclipse-LazyStart` (or `Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy` in Equinox 3.4+) the bundle will be activated upon first class **or resource** request.

Originally I meant to ask how one may add a resource file to activation exception list, as according to the documentation the exception list consists of class packages only:
`Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy; exclude:="org.eclipse.foo1, org.eclipse.foo2"`

But then I ran a few tests, and discovered that a bundle is not being activated upon a resource request - only class request activates a bundle. I was able to access my resource file and read its content without triggering bundle Activator.start.

So the question is:

- Is a bundle being activated upon a resource request? If it's not, it appears the documentation is misleading.
- If it is being activated, how a non-java file can be added to the exclude/include list? Why the Activator.start isn't being triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual OSGi specification for `Bundle-ActivationPolicy` says:

> By default, any class loaded from the bundle can trigger the lazy
> activation, however, resource loads must not trigger the activation.
> The lazy activation policy can define which classes cause the activation with the following directives:
>
> • include - A list of package names that must trigger the activation
> when a class is loaded from any of these packages. The default is all
> package names present in the bundle.
>
> • exclude - A list of package
> names that must not trigger the activation of the bundle when a class
> is loaded from any of these packages. The default is no package names.

(section 4.4.6.2 OSGi Core Release 6 June 2014)

So that is saying resources never trigger activation.